# Is it dangerous to use placement new on an old object without explicitly calling the destructor first?

Tags: c++, placement-new

I would like to recycle memory for an object rather than deallocating and reconstructing it. Is the following usage of "placement new" safe, assuming that `Foo` in practice does not contain pointers (but might contain functions)?

Also, is the final `delete` call safe, and will it correctly call the destructor on the second "new" object, and correctly free the memory afterwards?

```
#include <new>
struct Foo {
    int hello;
    int world;
};

int main() {
    Foo* foo = new Foo;
    // Do something with foo
    // Done with foo, writing a new version of foo on top of the old one.
    new(foo) Foo();

    delete(foo);
}
```

The simple example above compiles and runs without errors, but I cannot tell by running it whether it might blow up for some reason in a more complex environment.

Comment: The C++11 solution is to _move_ the new object over the old one. Both safe & efficient.

Comment: Why do you want to skip the destructor?

Comment: @PeteBecker, if it is unnecessary, I do not want to pay any performance cost for the function call when I just overwrite the memory with a placement new constructor.

Comment: @merlin2011 - if it is unnecessary (i.e., it is a trivial destructor) the compiler will skip it. If the destructor does something meaningful, it's necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not dangerous to reuse memory of an object, provided that you are doing it correctly. Moreover, you do not have to restrict yourself to objects that have no pointers: by calling the destructor explicitly you can prepare the object for reuse, like this:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo;
// Do something with foo
// Done with foo, writing a new version of foo on top of the old one.
foo->~Foo();     // Call the destructor explicitly to clean up the resources of a Foo
new(foo) Foo();  // Place new data into the previously allocated memory
delete(foo);     // We are deleting a fully initialized object, so it is OK
```

Comment: since `placement new` is happening, don't we need to call the `destructor` for the new object again?

Answer (score 7):

It's safe because the object you're overwriting has a trivial destructor. From n3337, chapter 3.8 (Object lifetime):

> 4 **A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies or by explicitly
>   calling the destructor for an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor.** For an object of a class type
>   with a non-trivial destructor, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly before the storage
>   which the object occupies is reused or released; however, if there is no explicit call to the destructor or if a
>   delete-expression (5.3.5) is not used to release the storage, the destructor shall not be implicitly called and
>   any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undeﬁned behavior.

The `delete` call is safe, too. You're calling it on a pointer that you got from `new` and there's a live object at that place.

And as you hinted in the question, it could invoke undefined behaviour if the destructor is non-trivial and has side effects - you need to call it explicitly in that case. Whether or not the class contains pointers is not directly important - reusing the storage is safe even in that case, but of course, you could introduce memory leaks and other bugs that way.

Comment: As you can see, standard does not say it will blow up when destructor is non-trivial. You'll get UB only if your program depends on the destructor side effects, but even UB doesn't necessarily mean blow up.

Comment: @KonstantinOznobihin Well yes, it *may*, but not neccesarily. Changed that.

Comment: well lot of relies on destructorss.. probably you can safely do that for pure data containers (probably most usefull stuff to get constructed in place because you avoid many small allocations)

Answer (score 2):

There have been two answers already, but they give, I fear, an incomplete picture.

You may reuse the storage of an object, providing that you respect a few conditions:

- You need not use a dynamically allocated object, **any object is fine**.
- You should properly **destroy the previous object**, by calling its destructor (explicitly); failure to do so leads to *undefined behavior* if the destructor has side-effects (see §3.8/4)
- The object that you place should have the **same dynamic type** as the previous object  (see §3.8/7)

Let us review them, starting with *any object is fine*:

```
struct Foo {
    int hello;
    int world;
};

void automatically_allocated() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.~Foo();
    new (&foo) Foo{};
}

void dynamically_allocated() {
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo{});
    foo->~Foo();
    new (&*foo) Foo{};
}
```

Let use continue with *destroy the previous object*:

```
struct Bar {
    int hello;
    std::string world;
};

void UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR() {
    Bar bar;
    new (&bar) Bar{}; // most likely scenario: leaks memory owned by bar.world
}
```

And finally with *same dynamic type*:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} };

struct Derived: Base { std::string world; };
struct Other: Base { int hello; }

void UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR() {
    Derived derived;

    Base& b = derived;
    b.~Base(); // fine

    new (&b) Other{};

    // Most likely here, calls "derived.~Derived()" on an object of type Other...
}
```

Comment: "...failure to do so leads to undefined behavior if the destructor has side-effects (see §3.8/4)" only if the program "depends" on the side effects. E.g., your second example has defined behavior.

Comment: @Casey: if you are talking about `Bar`, I would argue that a memory leak is a manifestation of *undefined behavior*; otherwise please precise which example...

Comment: I am speaking of `Bar`, yes. I claim that it has defined behavior just as `void foo() { new int; }` does; leaking memory has defined behavior.

Comment: @Casey: I can see your point of view, I guess, however I would recommend you consider that `Bar` was instead holding a lock ? or owning a file descriptor ? In general, the correctness of a program is based on proper release of acquired resources (lest it creates an OOM situation, a deadlock, ...); the expression *only if the program "depends" on the side effects* is intentionally vague, in my opinion, so as to address all those possible issues.

Comment: Yes, that is all true - and it illustrates that the situation is a bit more complicated than you've portrayed it to be with your claim that the function `UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR` *necessarily* has undefined behavior. The standard is clear here: leaking resources does not necessarily lead to undefined behavior unless enough resources are leaked so that the program is impacted be the resulting scarcity. You can say that it's horrible style, and that the writer should be flogged, and I'll agree with you all day long - but you can't say the standard forbids it.

Comment: @Casey: I think I see why we are at odds here. The Standard does not *forbid* undefined behavior, it just does not define it. Therefore the function exhibits undefined behavior because the Standard does not define what should happen, nothing less nothing more. As an example of undefined behavior, a conforming implementation of the STL would be within its rights to crash the program upon `new (&bar) Bar{};` when it realizes that `Bar::world` is going to be allocated where another `Bar::world` is still alive.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: How do they define "if the destructor has side-effects" here? For example if the destructor would do `fwrite` to some file, is that a side effect? What if we never read that file, meaning we never depended on the behavior of the destructor?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I am afraid it is ill-defined, which is annoying. Intuitively I think you have the gist of it: you should have been within your rights to expect some observable effects (release of resources, stuff written to a file, ...) and those effects did not occur... which may or may not have an impact. Let us not forget than *undefined behavior* does mean *crash*, but merely than anything could occur, including the fact that everything appears to work (which happens if you forget to verify that those effects did occur...)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I feel like the only logical definition is that the destructor isn't called... which means it's just like any other function. Right?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well, from a pragmatic point of view, I would think so; however the Standard places a special role on the destructor's shoulder (see the **basic.lifetime** paragraph) and I would guess they felt compelled to emphasize that not calling the destructor was invalidating some "conventions" previously established.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I can see they intended it to be special, but even my most convoluted interpretation just can't give me a consistent explanation that bears a different meaning. Here's an example: let's say we have a destructor that takes a random-number generator, generates a new random integer, and XORs it with an existing integer which was already randomly generated. Now let's say I forget to call this destructor. The integer was already random -- so am I "depending" on the result of the destructor? It's ridiculous and meaningless to say this is UB; the program is different after the XOR.