# MSVC inlines virtual function call when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, visual-c++, virtual

I'm trying to write some code where I can create a base class on the stack and modify the vtable with a call to that base class.

```
class Base
{
    public:
        void initAs(int version);
        virtual int foo() { assert(false); return 0; }
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    virtual int foo() { return 1; }
};

void Base::initAs(int version)
{
    switch(version)
    {
    case 1:
        new (this) A();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Base x;
    int version = 1;
    x.initAs(version);
    int v = x.foo();
    assert(v == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running into issues where x.foo() is inlined to call Base::foo() instead of A::foo(). I checked the disassembly, and there is no vtable resolution. The compiler decides to inline that virtual function even though it should be able to see that the memory pointing to x is getting modified. How can I get stop the compiler (MSVC 14) from inlining that function call x.foo() ?

EDIT:
I'm not looking for comments or answers on how undefined this behavior is. As far as I know, I should expect that x.foo() should go through the whole virtual function call stack since it is marked as a virtual function and nowhere do I attempt to fully qualify the function name (a.k.a. x.Base::foo() ). I have other places in the code where this does work:

```
class Container
{
private:
    Base x;
    Container();
    void foo();
};

Container::Container() { x.initAs(1); }
void Container::foo() { assert(x.foo() == 1; } // This call is correct A::foo()
```

Where is the discrepancy in the compiler and how can I turn it off?

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: The compiler is doing exactly what it should be doing. Your code has undefined behavior and your expectations are invalid.

Comment: Where is this marked as being undefined behavior? Can you give me a link?

Comment: Undefined behavior means *undefined*. Be glad [demons didn't fly from your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Complaining about it doesn't change anything. By the as-if rule, the compiler can change a virtual call to an inline one if it knows the static type of the object, and the undefined behavior is in trying to bypass what are compiler internals.

Comment: @DarthZaloj http://stackoverflow.com/a/20542142/845092

Comment: @MooingDuck That would be useful, except I don't care about whether the right or wrong destructor is called. I'm fine with Base::~Base() being invoked in my scenario. I'm not ok with the compiler inlining Base::foo() in there when I don't believe that I fully qualified it to be calling that function.

Comment: To get a virtual call you have to use a pointer or a reference. With the code `Base x; x.foo();` anyone can see that `x` is a `Base` - it says so in the code.

Comment: @BoPersson But in my second example, anyone can see that Container::x is a Base and yet the compiler doesn't inline it for that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot make a comment, and I haven't experimented with the stuff myself, but I want to make the following observation - you probably cannot force the compiler to not inline the function. Compilers are notoriously inconsistent when it comes to inlining, even the `inline` keyword doesn't force it to inline (its more like a hint, and it also makes the function invisible to other compilation units), and the absence of the `inline` keyword doesn't mean it cannot inline. This strongly indicates that the best you can do is to try to bypass it somehow.

I have not tried this one myself (and it would be a bit strange if it worked, though if we are to believe the comments it should..), but the idea is that now you have a reference, and to resolve them requires virtual lookup (yada).

```
int main()
{
    Base x_on_stack;
    Base &x = x_on_stack;
    int version = 1;
    x.initAs(version);
    int v = x.foo();
    assert(v == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will say that doing your reference workaround and even doing (&x_on_stack)->foo() will achieve the behavior I want. __declspec(noinline) doesn't work either. A coworker thinks that a memory aliasing feature in the compiler is broken which causes this preoptimization. I am now investigating how clang performs with this example.